# How to use ivy to build a war with out copying jars to a lib directory

Tags: ant, ivy

My goal is have my ant build script build a war file and include the jars that ivy knows this project depends on. The best code I could come up with at the moment is the following

```
<mkdir dir="dist/lib"/>
<ivy:retrieve pattern="dist/lib/[artifact].[ext]" sync="true"/>
<war destfile="dist/${ivy.module}.war" basedir="build" includes="**/*.class"
    webxml="${war.webxml}">
    <fileset dir="${war.web}"/>
    <lib dir="dist/lib"/>
</war>
```

The problem with this code is it copies the jars twice. Once in to my dist/lib directory and again in to the war when it's created. It works but I can't shake the feeling there is a better way.

What I would like to do is something more like the following

```
<ivy:cachepath pathid="locpathref.classpath"/>
<war destfile="dist/${ivy.module}.war" basedir="build" includes="**/*.class"
    webxml="${war.webxml}">
    <fileset dir="${war.web}"/>
    <lib refid="locpathref.classpath"/>
</war>
```

The problem is that the lib tag does not take in a refid of any kind. Any ideas or am I stuck with an extra set of file copies?

Comment: Use <ivy:cachefileset setid="locpathref.classpath" conf="runtime"/> then the lib tag will work as expected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that the **lib** tag is a custom **fileset** that  targets it's files into the war archive's *lib* sub directory. It might be possible to write a custom **war** task but I don't think it's worth the effort.

If want to improve the manner in which ivy manages your war's dependencies might I suggest using configurations?

Create a configuration describing the run-time dependencies:

```
    <ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="apache" module="hello-ivy"/>
    <configurations>
        <conf name="build" description="Libraries needed to for compilation"/>
        <conf name="war" extends="build" description="Libraries that should be included in the war file" />
    </configurations>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="commons-lang" name="commons-lang" rev="2.0" conf="build->*,!sources,!javadoc"/>
        <dependency org="commons-cli" name="commons-cli" rev="1.0" conf="build->*,!sources,!javadoc"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

Afterwards you retrieve them into a dedicated directory (using a pattern) which can be simply included using the **war** task's **lib** tag:

```
    <ivy:retrieve pattern="${lib.dir}/[conf]/[artifact].[ext]"/>

    <war destfile="${war.file}" webxml="${resources.dir}/web.xml">
        <fileset dir="${resources.dir}" excludes="web.xml"/>
        <lib dir="${lib.dir}/war"/>
    </war>
```

The advantage of this approach is that you use the ivy **conf** attribute of each project dependency to ultimately decide if the jar gets included within the war file or not. The build file no longer cares.

In conclusion I understand that the point of your post was concern for multiple copies of your jar files... Using my suggested approach will further multiple your copies, but I would submit that this is not an issue provided you have a *clean* target to remove them afterwards.

Comment: I agree that this is a better solution then what I am doing but it still does not remove the extra file copy as I would like. The more I look at this the more I think that, as you said, the only real way to fix is by creating a custom war task or even a new custom lib task for the war task. In a perfect world this new task could would day become part of Ivy or Ant.

Comment: The solution you want is to use the ivy cachefileset task instead of cachepath. Then the refid parameter to the warfile's lib tag will work as expected

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Ant 1.8, you can use the technique described here:
http://www.beilers.com/2010/06/ivy-dependency-management-lessons-learned-and-ant-1-8-mapped-resources/

EXAMPLE:

```
<war destfile="${war.full.path}" webxml="WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml" manifest="${manifest.path}">
    <fileset dir="WebContent">
     </fileset>
    <classes dir="${build.dir}"/>

    <mappedresources>
      <restrict>
        <path refid="classpath.CORE"/>
        <type type="file"/>
      </restrict>
      <chainedmapper>
        <flattenmapper/>
        <globmapper from="*" to="WEB-INF/lib/*"/>
      </chainedmapper>
    </mappedresources>

    <zipfileset dir="src" prefix="WEB-INF/classes">
         <include name="**/resources/**/*.properties" />
         <include name="**/resources/**/*.xml" />
    </zipfileset>
</war>
```

Comment: Very interesting ... I will try this and report!