# Maven-Ant dependency problem

Tags: ant, maven

I am trying to make a build file for a Java project in eclipse using Maven and Ant. However, I can't make the maven-ant-tasks dependency work. Can anybody help me on what to do with this? Maybe my URL and file is wrong. Here it is:

```
  <property name="maven.ant.dir" value="http://apache.hoxt.com/maven/binaries"/>

  <property name="maven.ant.file" value="http://apache.hoxt.com/maven/binaries/maven-ant-tasks-2.1.3.jar"/>
```

Comment: Can you post the snippet where you use these properties?  Also what is the error that you get?

Comment: I was able to resolve it although I used an internal Maven repository. There should be another for ant tasks that is in the web. That's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how the Maven ANT task works

```
<project .. xmlns:artifact="antlib:org.apache.maven.artifact.ant">
  ..
  <target name="retrieve" description="Retrieve dependencies using Maven">

     <artifact:dependencies filesetId="compile.fileset" useScope="compile">
        <pom file="${pom.dir}/pom.xml"/>
     </artifact:dependencies>

     <copy todir="${retrieve.dir}/compile">
        <fileset refid="compile.fileset" />
        <mapper type="flatten" />
     </copy>
     ..
```

Documentation is [here](http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/index.html)

Comment: How to include retrieved jar files in WAR file?

Comment: @ImranAli I don't think I understand your question... I can suggest that you look at the "lib" tag that is associated with the ANT "war" task: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/war.html

Comment: thanks for ur reply. I want to include maven dependencies jar libraries in WAR file. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25902727/how-to-include-maven-dependency-libraries-in-war-file-using-ant-build

Comment: @ImranAli Here's a similar example. Note the "lib" tag in war task. My example uses ivy to download the dependencies, but the principle is the same. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078007/how-to-use-ivy-to-build-a-war-with-out-copying-jars-to-a-lib-directory/2124023#2124023